# symfony and ratchet Call to a member function get() on null

Tags: php, database, symfony, websocket, ratchet

I using symfony and ratchet web socket to connect to database and changing value in a certain column if someone connect to the server but I get error in this line

```
        $conn = $this->get('database_connection');
```

Call to a member function get() on null

my services.yml file

```
services:
     checkrooms.example:
         class: check\roomsBundle\Sockets\Chat
         arguments: ["@database_connection"]
         calls:
             - [setContainer, ['@service_container']]
```

my Chat.php code

```
    namespace check\roomsBundle\Sockets;
    use tuto\testBundle\Entity\Users;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
    use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface; 


    class Chat extends Controller implements MessageComponentInterface  {
        protected $clients;
        public function __construct() {
            $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;

        }



        public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
            $this->clients->attach($conn);
    //database part
            echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
            $conn = $this->get('database_connection');
            $users = $conn->query("UPDATE user SET Batman= '1999' WHERE UserId='2'");



        }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the complete error message? Including the file and line at which the error occurred? It's easy to find the issue from the message the method `get()` is being called on null, meaning that the variable `$this` is not assigned to anything and PHP reads something like `null->get()`. Since `$this` is a pseudo variable inside an object context, like the class you are in, this is very unlikely. You probably have another call to `get()` from a different variable or your code is not in a class' function.

Comment: my full error message on terminal  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
  Call to a member function get() on null

Comment: i included the error line already         $conn = $this->get('database_connection');

Comment: `$this->container->get('database_connection');` - $this-get() is a shortcut and if you want to use it you have to extend base controller, otherwise use $this->container->get().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use:

```
$this->container->get('database_connection');
```

because you call method `setContainer` and it looks like this:

```
    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
{
    $this->container = $container;
}
```

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerAwareTrait.php#L31

`$this->get()` is a shortcut only, you can use it if you extend base controller:

```
  protected function get($id)
{
    return $this->container->get($id);
}
```

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php#L410

Comment: i tried to use $this->container->get('database_connection'); and i still get the same error

Comment: He is already extending the controller (which he probably should not) so get is available.  The basic problem is that he is new'ing chat instead of pulling from the container.  And of course since the connection is being injected then there is no need to inject the container in the first place.  Just needs to spend some time understanding dependency injection.